# What is difrence betwean domain class save and session save

Tags: grails

Could someone explain the difference to me between these code samples (Grails 3.3.11)

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()
 Person person           = new Person()
 person.firstName        = "John"
 person.lastName         = "Roy"
 person.address          = "New York"
 session.save(person)
```

and

```
 Person person           = new Person()
 person.firstName        = "John"
 person.lastName         = "Roy"
 person.address          = "New York"
 person.save(person)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One difference is that `session.save(person)` will work with any entity that is mapped in that Hibernate session where `person.save()` only works with GORM entities (which are also mapped in the Hibernate session for you).

When using GORM there really aren't good reasons to use `session.save(person)`.

I know that you didn't ask about best practice or about GORM Data Service but related to your question...

With recent versions of GORM best practice would be to have an abstract GORM Data Service like this...

```
import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(Person)
interface PersonService {
    Person save(Person p)
}
```

And then inject that wherever you want to do the save.  For example, in a controller:

```
class SomeController {
    PersonService personService

    def someAction() {
        Person p = new Person()

        // ...

        personService.save p

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: We are looking for ways to make bulk inserts faster. What is the best practice for bulk inserts and updates in recent GORM versions. Session.save looks much faster. What are possible risks or downsides using session save for grails app ?

Comment: "What is the best practice for bulk inserts and updates in recent GORM versions" - There are some docs about batch updates at http://gorm.grails.org/7.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html.